# SharePoint 2013 hiding ribbon stops scrolling

Tags: javascript, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

Recently I have been working on SharePoint 2013 master page. It's a fixed width design.
The requirement is that, only the users who have **edit permission**  can see the ribbon can see the top sharepoint top ribbon bar. Otherwise all the users who has only view or contribute permission cannot see the ribbon bar. I used **SPSecurityTrimmedControl** to wrap the **ms-designer-ribbon** div , so that only the users who have edit permission can see the designer ribbon bar.

Problem is that, after publishing the master page the scroll bar is gone.
I added ***overflow:auto;*** on the body and it shows the scroll bar. But again another problems appears. When I login with a user who has edit permission , it shows two scroll on the right.

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="EditListItems">-->
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <!--SID:02 {Ribbon}-->
            <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="background: rgb(0, 114, 198); color: white; width: 100%; padding: 8px; height: 64px; overflow: hidden;">The SharePoint ribbon will be here when your file is either previewed on or applied to your site.</div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
        </div>
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
```

Problem is , after publishing the master page the scroll bar is gone.
I added ***overflow:auto;*** on the body and it shows the scroll bar. But again another problems appears. When I login with a user who has edit permission , it shows two scroll on the right.

How can I solve this issue , any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="ms-designer-ribbon" style="display:none">
    <!--SID:02 {Ribbon}-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="background: rgb(0, 114, 198); color: white; width: 100%; padding: 8px; height: 64px; overflow: hidden;">The SharePoint ribbon will be here when your file is either previewed on or applied to your site.</div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
</div>  

<!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="EditListItems">-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#ms-designer-ribbon').show();
        });
    </script>
<!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
```

Comment: Hasim thanks for your reply, but I have one question.
Any one can find the div **#ms-designer-ribbon** and remove its style 'display:none'. Is there any work around about this issue?

Comment: In that case you should use some server side code. Also try placing `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` inside `<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">` and check if that resolved the scroll issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set ***overflow:visible*** on ***#s4-workspace*** then that should get rid of the second scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I like Amal Hashim's solution (in theory because I haven't tried it), however it presupposes that the master page load jQuery.

You can achieve the same result using just CSS. In the HEAD section of the master page add:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="EditListItems">
<style>#ms-designer-ribbon {display:block}</style> 
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

And just add

```
style="display:none"
```

in the DIV that displays the Ribbon